# Prevent dropdown close when use navtabs [bootstrap 4]

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What I have:

-Bootstrap 4

-Navbar>Dropdown>Navtabs

When I press the link in navtabs, the dropdown closes. How I can repair it?

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown09">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="padding-top: 1%">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#trud" role="tab">Трудовые единицы</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Профиль</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="trud" role="tabpanel">
                  somthing 1
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">
                    something 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" role="menu">...

$("document").ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {
      if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-menu-form')) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
  });
});
```